# Confidence Interval Based on Asymptotic Normality in lmer model

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, mixed-models, random-effects

Why is not `confint.default` which is based on asymptotic normality doesn't work for `lmer` model ?

```
fit <- lmer(y~(1|operator)+(1|part),data=dat)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: y ~ (1 | operator) + (1 | part)
 Data: dat
REML criterion at convergence: 409.3913
Random effects:
Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
part     (Intercept) 3.2018  
operator (Intercept) 0.1031  
Residual             0.9398  
Number of obs: 120, groups:  part, 20; operator, 3
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
     22.39  


 confint.default(fit)
 Error in as.integer(x) : 
   cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'integer'
```

What is the error saying ? How can I get confidence interval based on asymptotic normality for lmer model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `confint.default()`, just use `confint()`. The methods to calculate confidence intervals are different for the different model types. You can see the different methods with `methods(confint)`. The "correct" version of the function is called based on the class of the first object you pass to the function. Directly calling one of the methods usually isn't a good idea.

There are options for how to calculate the bounds for the `lmer` objects. Look at the help page for `?confint.merMod` to see the options unique to that model type.

Answer (score 2):

@MrFlick is correct, but it may be worth adding that `confint.merMod()` gives likelihood profile CIs by default; `confint(.,method="Wald")` will give the confidence intervals based on asymptotic normality:

> ‘"Wald"’: approximating the confidence intervals (of fixed-effect
>             parameters only; all variance-covariance parameters CIs will
>             be returned as ‘NA’) based on the estimated local curvature
>             of the likelihood surface;

(this is obvious from the help page, but is probably worth restating here).